# TLP Full Charge

Tags: battery, tlp

"Charge Full" and "Charge Full Design" show different values. Are they supposed to? It's a Dell Inspiron 7378, barely two months old. Also, tlp has a flag: tlp fullcharge. Will that push my charge full value to be equal to full charge design value? I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.
[screenshot of tlp stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iwlI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charge full (Design) indicates the maximum amount of charge the battery should store from the factory.

Charge full indicates the maximum amount of charge the battery is currently estimated to store.  If this is lower than the previous value, it indicates the battery is thought to have deteriorated since it was new.

Batteries don't just lose capacity due to mistreatment.  Simply being left on the shelf will age them a bit.  If your battery spent two years in a warehouse before you purchased it, it may have lost a small amount of capacity.

You can't recover capacity through software.  Assuming that the battery's estimate of its current capacity is correct, there is no way to recover the original capacity.  That said, the figure is an estimate and may not always be accurate in cases where damage has occurred to the battery, the battery hasn't deteriorated as much as expected, or other unexpected conditions have caused changes in the battery capacity.

Comment: But that would mean my battery capacity has deteriorated by 20% already (barely two months old).  So basically I'm at a loss with a device straight out of the box?

Comment: It could be an inaccurate reading, or the battery could have been "on the shelf" for a long time before you bought it. Probably you wouldn't be able to make warranty claim unless you could show actual poor capacity by testing it ie not just relying on that indicator.

Comment: Sometimes those values might not be read correctly during connected to the power supply